# Okta Spring Security Integration Multiple Issuers

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, okta

I've connected Okta with Spring Security for server-to-server communication and everything is working as expected(client credentials approach). However, I need to support JWT validation in resource servers issued from 2 different authorization servers(by Okta) in the resource server. How can I support this in Spring Boot or any idea how to handle it manually maybe. I'm using Okta spring boot starter to make validation etc for JWT and added the following properties for fetching keys for JWT validation.

```
okta.oauth2.issuer=https://{account_number}.okta.com/oauth2/xyz
okta.oauth2.audience=test
```

Now, the second server has a different issuer URL, but I want to support JWTs created from the second authorization server as well. Authorization servers are different because they had different scopes to support.

Any answer will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use multiple 'JWK Set Uri' values in the same Spring Boot app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60031919/how-do-i-use-multiple-jwk-set-uri-values-in-the-same-spring-boot-app)